# Better way to handle slow internet in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit library for api's .I just want to know better way to handle slow internet.
Should i handle the timeout in error or should i download some file from the internet & calculate how long it took vs number of bytes in the file ?

Currently i am handling SocketTimeoutException and SocketException in onFailure.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.SERVER_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build())
                .build();
```

Comment: But this will give me timeout after 30 seconds. so it will show in onFailure which i am already handling. i am asking about better way.

Comment: Slow internet does not mean it would take 30 seconds to load the minute json data. onFailure method is called upon other other scenerio as well.

Comment: @AmitBhandari Yes but i am handling SocketTimeoutException and SocketException for time out and any socket connection (network issue) in onFailure. 
Is that fine ?

Comment: @ʌɐɥqıɐʌ In my case, I use onFailure for server down and LAN with no real internet access(which is also socketTimeoutExcetion). So I think, we are useing it for same general purposes :)